# Is this the way to create a PyTorch scalar?

Tags: python, pytorch

I'm new to PyTorch, and just wanted to kindly confirm if the following creates scalars with values, 1, 2, and 3, respectively?

```
import torch

a = torch.tensor(1)
b = torch.tensor(2)
c = torch.tensor(3)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Important footgun: torch.Tensor(3) does *not* do the same thing as torch.tensor(3)! The first creates an uninitalized tensor with shape [3], the second creates a scalar with value 3.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

From the example in the documentation for [`torch.tensor`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.tensor):

```
>>> torch.tensor(3.14159)  # Create a scalar (zero-dimensional tensor)
tensor(3.1416)
```

Therefore, it appears they endorse that passing a number creates the corresponding scalar.

Comment: What could be a usecase of creating a Pytorch scalar? Suppose I have a `B` as a PyTorch float tensor, then isn't `B * 3.14` same as `B * torch.tensor(3.14)`? If same why ever create a PyTorch scalar?

Comment: @MohitLamba One use case: If you want to use PyTorch's JIT tracing functionality your functions can only take `torch.Tensor` typed arguments (and tuples, lists and dicts thereof). So instead of `my_function(f: float, t: torch.Tensor)` your function needs to read `my_function(f: torch.Tensor, t: torch.Tensor)`.

Answer (score 3):

You can further check what is in your tensor.

```
import torch
t = torch.tensor(1)
print(t.size())
print(t.ndim)
print(t.numel())
print(t.stride())
print(t.element_size())
print(t.type())
```

And keep track that PyTorch can create tensors by data and by dimension.

```
import torch
# by data
t = torch.tensor([1., 1.])
# by dimension
t = torch.zeros(2,2)
```

Your case was to create tensor by data which is a scalar: `t = torch.tensor(1)`.
But this also is a scalar: `t = torch.tensor([1])` imho because it has a size and no direction. ;)